# Converting from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle

Using XML, the code piece in question looks like:

```
<field  name="case"
when max(b.expected_date) %lt% current_date then %q%0000-00-00%q%
else to_char(max(b.expected_date), %q%YYYY-MM-DD%q%)
end"
title="QoO Expected"
type="Date" />
```

I have tried changing to_char to convert and current_date to getdate. Nothing is working so far. Here are my changes:

```
<field  name="case"
when max(b.potduedate) %lt% getdate then %q%0000-00-00%q%
else convert (max(b.potduedate), %q%YYYY-MM-DD%q%)
end"
title="QoO Expected"
type="Date" />
```

The error I receive is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'b.potduedate'., SQL state 37000

Answer (score 1):

getdate is a function in Oracle, so you may need to add () to get this to work.

```
getdate()
```